# How to play a microphone out of a speaker?

Tags: amplifier, microphone, electret

So I have a small amplifier that plugs into a 12V source and a standard 3.5mm headphone jack and plays pretty good sound to a 8ohm speaker. I am wondering if I can connect the 3.5mm headphone jack to an electret microphone and play the sound from the microphone out of the speaker. I guess I am wondering what kind of voltage the mp3 player outputs. Since that work great with the amp I guess I am wondering how to get an electret microphone to the leverl where I could input it into the same amplifier.

Comment: Microphone needs to be biased for proper operation. So you cannot directly connect a mic to your 3.5mm jack

Comment: Related: I used it the other way around. I plugged headphones into a microphone jack. It worked, it wasn't perfect but it did the job as a maleshift solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Op's question reminds of a tricky question paper :) . What I construde is;

- 1) 3.5mm Jack= O/P (looks like an I/p).
- 2) He wants to insert electret microphone into this jack .

But If he is listening to something with MP3 then the *Jack is not an output device* , he probably has an additional speaker somewhere ?? .If this is true then Jack is an I/P connector. The electret mic cannot be inserted directly, you need biasing as below .
[image]

It would be better to add a pre-amplification stage as below;

[image]
from: [here](http://circuit-diagram.hqew.net/Electret-Microphone-Pre$2damp-based-NE5532_12012.html)

When you plug into the microphone , slowly adjust the gain of your opamp and O/P volume of your amplifier such that feedback is eleminated.

Comment: What is `R8` for?

Comment: @sherrellbc, Thanks for pointing out that it probably might be a careless mistake . I have rectified it along with other site link.

Comment: Is it assumed that the mic in this schematic includes a decoupling capacitor at its output? Also, I have never seen a mic amplifier like this. Typically they are just common-emitted amplifiers. What is the purpose of `C1` and `R3? It appears to be some kind of high-pass filter for the feedback loop?

Comment: @sherrellbc, R3 and R4 sets the gain and C1 is there for  providing  ac ground to audio signal for this single supply preamp.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if I can connect the 3.5mm headphone jack to an
>   electret microphone and play the sound from the microphone out of the
>   speaker.

No you can't. The headphone jack is an output; a microphone requires to be connected to an input so that it can be amplified.

Comment: While the wording of the question is not great, I think the OP may be referring to the 3.5mm headphone jack as being the input connector for an amplifier.

Comment: @PeterJ you may indeed be right. Time will tell.